# java-script cannot clear the Radtextbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, getelementbyid

Sir/Madam

I am going to create a a form with a reset button which can clear the fields of the form

But the function cannot work. The previous record entered in the box is still here.
Would you please tell the methodology to clear the forms on the CLIENT SIDE ?

the below is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

     ...
        function ClearForms(sender, args) {

            document.getElementById('<%=txtRemeasureCode.ClientID%>').innerText() = "";
            document.getElementById('<%=dapSubmitTo.ClientID%>').clear();
            document.getElementById('<%=dapSubmitFrom.ClientID%>').clear();


        }
 .. .

      <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtRemeasureCode" Width="200px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />    

  ....
           <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dapSubmitFrom" runat="server" MinDate="2010-01-01" AutoPostBack="false"            Width="200px">
                        <Calendar ID="CalendarFrom" RangeMinDate="2010-01-01" runat="server">
                        </Calendar>

         <DatePopupButton ImageUrl="" HoverImageUrl=""></DatePopupButton>

             <DateInput DisplayDateFormat="yyyy-M-d" DateFormat="yyyy-M-d" runat="server" ></DateInput>
                     </telerik:RadDatePicker>
              .....
                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dapSubmitTo" runat="server" MinDate="2010-01-01" AutoPostBack="false"                      Width="200px">
                        <Calendar ID="CalendarTo" RangeMinDate="2010-01-01" runat="server">
                        </Calendar>

             <DatePopupButton ImageUrl="" HoverImageUrl=""></DatePopupButton>

           <DateInput DisplayDateFormat="yyyy-M-d" DateFormat="yyyy-M-d" runat="server"></DateInput>
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>



              ...........

               ..............

                <telerik:RadButton ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClientClick="ClearForms;return false">
                     <Icon PrimaryIconUrl="~/Image/Button/reset.gif" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4" />
                </telerik:RadButton>
```

Comment: you are having problem with RadTextbox only or all other rad controls?

Comment: mainly for the button and javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working code :

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged" > 
    <Items> 
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="0" Text="" /> 
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="1" Text="One" /> 
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="2" Text="Two" /> 
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="3" Text="Three" /> 
    </Items> 
</telerik:RadComboBox> 

<telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" /> 

<asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" OnClientClicked="ClearValues();return false;" Text="Clear" /> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function SelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) 
{ 
    if (args.get_item().get_value() != 0) 
    { 
        var textBoxNewValue = args.get_item().get_value() + ": " + args.get_item().get_text(); 
        $find("<%= RadTextBox1.ClientID %>").set_value(textBoxNewValue); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $find("<%= RadTextBox1.ClientID %>").clear(); 
    } 
} 

function ClearValues() 
{ 
    $find("<%= RadTextBox1.ClientID %>").clear(); 
    $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>").clearSelection(); 
} 

</script>
```

Comment: In your code, I see OnClientClick="ClearForms;return false". It should be OnClientClick="ClearForms(); return false;" ClearForms() should be called as method.